# Binding multiple list in Datagrid

Tags: wpf, xaml

I need to achieve a result like this:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kqgbC.png)

xaml doesn't allow to create row via code, so I though to implement the row logic as a list. Each list is a row.

What I did essentially is this:

```
LastFiveHomeAwayMatches2 = new List<List<string>>()
                {
                  new List<string> {"Accrington", "D", "D", "W", "W", "W", "11" },
                  new List<string> { string.Empty, "1-1", "0-0", "0-1", "4-2", "0-3", string.Empty },
                  new List<string> {"Fos", "D", "D", "W", "W", "W", "11" },
                  new List<string> { string.Empty, "1-1", "0-0", "0-1", "4-2", "0-3", string.Empty },
                };
```

but how can I bind this multiple list in the Datagrid to achieve the result displayed? thanks.
**Update**

```
<DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
         ItemsSource="{Binding MatchController.LatestFiveMatches}">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                   <DataGridTextColumn Header="Teams" />
                                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="5" />
                                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="4" />
                                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="3" />
                                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="2" />
                                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="1" />
                                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Pt."/>
                                </DataGrid.Columns>

                            </DataGrid>
```

this doesn't display nothing. I need to display as header columns `Teams, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1` also if the datagrid is blank.

Comment: it is the 4th time I see this question in a slightly different wording. sigh. consider using DataTable where rows are filled with your values (a simple example here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44206066/1506454). Disable DataGrid sorting though, or the rows can be reordered otherwise

Comment: seems some stackoverflow users hate me, idk, I got banned for a question well explained, so no idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace `List<string>` with a type that has a public property for each column you want to display, e.g.:

```
LastFiveHomeAwayMatches2 = new List<RowType>()
            {
              new RowType { Team = "Accrington", A = "D", B = "D", C = "W", D = "W", E = "W", F = "11" },
              ...
            };
dataGrid.ItemsSource = LastFiveHomeAwayMatches2;
```

---

```
public class RowType
{
    public string Team { get; set; }
    public string A { get; set; }
    public string B { get; set; }
    public string C { get; set; }
    public string D { get; set; }
    public string E { get; set; }
    public string F { get; set; }
}
```

Edit:

Also note that you must bind each column to the corresponding property:

```
<DataGridTextColumn Header="Teams" Binding="{Binding Team}" />
```

Comment: this is an elegant and simple solution, thank you. Just one question I need to display to the user the blank column as `Teams, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, Pt.` I added an update to the question to show you my datagrid, anyway, not seems to display nothing.

Comment: See my edit. You need to bind each column to the corresponding property of the RowType class.