# MvvM Light - Bind dynamic 2D array to a wpf datagrid

Tags: c#, arrays, wpf, mvvm, datagrid

I would like to bind a 2D array to a datagrid in wpf.
My code looks like this (C# and wpf):

```
Table = new Collection<string[]>();
Table.Add(new string[] { "one", "two", "three" });
Table.Add(new string[] { "a1", "a2", "a3" });
Table.Add(new string[] { "b1", "b2", "b3" });
Table.Add(new string[] { "c1", "c2", "c3" });
Table.Add(new string[] { "d1", "d2", "d3" });

<StackPanel>
    <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Table}"></DataGrid>
</StackPanel>
```

This is what the table currently looks like:

[image: Table picture]

What is would like to see is "one", "two" and "three" in the table header, and the rest of the array rows as the content of the table.

Cheers

Comment: consider using DataTable instead of collection of arrays as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44202718/how-to-build-a-wpf-datagrid-with-an-unknown-number-of-columns)

Comment: @ASh Thanks for the comment! will look into it :)