# WPF: Bind List to Grid/DataGrid/ItemControl For Custom Display

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have the following sample list of object. They are just sample but in my actual application the results are based on the search criteria. In my example I have 3 persons and I want to display them in tabular format, can be grid, datagrid, itemcontrol etc. as long as I can bind the items. The number of rows and columns are dynamic therefore I cannot specify the number of columns and rows in design time. They must be dynamic. In my example I have list of 3 persons. I want to display them similar to the desired output screenshot. In my example I have

1. Fix first column named "Properties". This column lists all properties of the class or object. They too can be dynamic since the results came from database. There maybe for example Address, Gender, Contact number etc. and they should be displayed in first column only.
2. The columns PId1, PId2, and PId3 should be dynamic. For example I have another items PId4, PId5 so on and so forth. They must be added as new columns.

Please help me how to achieve the output. What control should I use? I want to bind it in the list.

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Windows;

namespace DataGridDemo
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public ObservableCollection<Person> Persons { get; set; }
        public int RowCount { get; set; }
        public MainWindow()
        {

            InitializeComponent();
            Persons = new ObservableCollection<Person>();
            Persons.Add(new Person { Name = "Mark", Age = 16, Id="PId1" });
            Persons.Add(new Person { Name = "Cyrus", Age = 18, Id= "PId2" });
            Persons.Add(new Person { Name = "David", Age = 20, Id= "PId3" });
            this.DataContext = this;
        }
    }
    public class Person
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Age { get; set; }
        public string Id { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**MainWindow.xaml (Fixed rows and columns for presentation only)**

```
<Window x:Class="DataGridDemo.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:DataGridDemo"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Grid>
        <Grid Width="400">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
                <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
                <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
                <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="20"></RowDefinition>
                <RowDefinition Height="20"></RowDefinition>
                <RowDefinition Height="20"></RowDefinition>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <TextBlock Text="Properties" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0"></TextBlock>
            <TextBlock Text="PId1" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1"></TextBlock>
            <TextBlock Text="PId2" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2"></TextBlock>
            <TextBlock Text="PId3" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="3"></TextBlock>
            <TextBlock Text="Name" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0"></TextBlock>
            <TextBlock Text="Mark" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1"></TextBlock>
            <TextBlock Text="Cyrus" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2"></TextBlock>
            <TextBlock Text="David" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="3"></TextBlock>
            <TextBlock Text="Age" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0"></TextBlock>
            <TextBlock Text="16" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1"></TextBlock>
            <TextBlock Text="18" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="2"></TextBlock>
            <TextBlock Text="20" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="3"></TextBlock>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

**Desired Output**

[image]

**The closest thing that I want to achieve something like this in the DPReview Camera Comparisons**

[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44202718/how-to-build-a-wpf-datagrid-with-an-unknown-number-of-columns

Answer (score 0):

Just bind the itemsSource attribute to your observable collection (in your case its Persons).

then in your xaml you use datatemplate and create visual items as you like and bind it to properties of your Model Class

Test this in your Xaml

```
<StackPanel>
    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Persons,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" >
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <TextBlock Width="100" Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                    <TextBlock Width="100" Text="{Binding Age}"/>
                    <TextBlock Width="100" Text="{Binding Id}"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
</StackPanel>
```

I know its not exactly as you described in pic, but it is simple to work your way out to there.