# Binding List<List<object>> to DataGrid columns in code-behind

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, datagrid, code-behind

I have a problem binding List<List> to DataGrid columns in code-behind.
Here is my list of lists:

```
private List<List<object>> matrix = new List<List<object>>()
     {
         new List<object>(){53, 2500, 3000, 3500, 4000, 4500, 5000},
         new List<object>(){2500, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
         new List<object>(){3000, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0},
         new List<object>(){3500, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0},
         new List<object>(){4000, 0, 0, 0},
         new List<object>(){4500, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0},
         new List<object>(){5000, 9, 7, 5, 4, 1, 1},
         new List<object>(){1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
         new List<object>(){2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
         new List<object>(){0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}
     };

    public List<List<object>> Matrix
    {
        get { return matrix; }
        set
        {
            matrix = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Matrix));
        }
```

I've done this in XAML like this:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Matrix}" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontSize="14" x:Name="matrixDataGrid" Height="420" Width="630" MinRowHeight="20" AutoGenerateColumns="False" >
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=[0], Mode=TwoWay}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=[1], Mode=TwoWay}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=[2], Mode=TwoWay}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=[3], Mode=TwoWay}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=[4], Mode=TwoWay}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=[5], Mode=TwoWay}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=[6], Mode=TwoWay}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=[7], Mode=TwoWay}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=[8], Mode=TwoWay}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=[9], Mode=TwoWay}"/>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

And here is the result:
[the result of XAML binding](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5zvM0.png)

And I would call it half-working. The first problem is an extra row and 3 extra columns. The second one is that I will have a lot of work if I would like to have 1000 columns. Also, there are a lot of XAML binding errors: [Binding errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CUXhC.png). And I don't even know how this specific binding works, and it looks strange. I would be glad for the explanation.

My unsuccessful attempts to do this in code-behind look like this:

```
Binding binding = new Binding();
binding.Source = Matrix; 
binding.Path = new PropertyPath("[0]"); 
binding.Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay;
columnOne.Binding = binding;
```

XAML file at the moment:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Matrix}" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontSize="14" x:Name="matrixDataGrid" Height="420" Width="630" MinRowHeight="20" AutoGenerateColumns="False" >
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Width="50" x:Name="columnOne" />
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

I only get empty column: [result of attempt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tPZTp.png).
I've seen someone doing this with DataTable, but I would like to do this the way I want if it is possible.

Comment: Do you have to use a DataGrid for this?

Comment: Actually, no, but it looks like the best way to represent such data.

Comment: Supporting an arbitrary number of columns in a DataGrid is relatively difficult.

Comment: @JohnV Yes, that is what I really felt when faced with that problem, but if there is a way to do such binding that my question is about it would be enough for me.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44202718/how-to-build-a-wpf-datagrid-with-an-unknown-number-of-columns

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wouldn't mess with a `DataGrid`, it's just too much hassle unless you need specific features of the `DataGrid` like sortable headers, grouping, etc. `DataGrid` also will not handle a huge matrix very well, since each cell is pretty heavy UI wise.

Instead, Since you have a `List` of `List`s, you can do the same thing with an `ItemsControl` of `ItemsControl`s. As long as each element has the same height/width, then it would come out looking just like the `DataGrid`. You could do that by fixing the size of each element, or set the `ItemsPanel` to something that enforces consistent sizing (like `UniformGrid`).

To make binding work so the cells are editable, you need to wrap the value in each matrix cell in something that implements INotifyPropertyChanged.

```
public class ItemViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler? PropertyChanged;
    private void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string p = null) 
        => PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this,new PropertyChangedEventArgs(p));
      
    private int _value;
    public int Value
    {
        get => _value;
        set
        {
           _value = value;
           OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public static implicit operator int(Item i) => i.Value;
    public static implicit operator Item(int i) => new () { Value = i};

    public static int[] GetArray(IEnumerable<Item> input) 
        => input.Select(i => i.Value).ToArray();

    public static int[][] GetMatrix(IEnumerable<IEnumerable<Item>> input) 
        => input.Select(ToArray).ToArray();
}
```

Here's the XAML for a MatrixGrid, derived from ItemsControl. The code behind doesn't have anything in it but the autogenerated constructor.

```xml
<ItemsControl x:Class="WpfApp1.MatrixGrid" x:Name="ic"
              xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
              xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
              ItemsSource="{Binding}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding}">
                <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <UniformGrid Columns="{Binding ElementName=ic, Path=ItemsSource.Count}"/>
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBox Text="{Binding Value, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                                 TextAlignment="Center"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            </ItemsControl>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

Demo:

```xml
<Window x:Class="WpfApp1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp1">
    <local:MatrixGrid x:Name="matrixGrid"/>
</Window>
```

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        matrixGrid.ItemsSource = Matrix;
    }

    public List<List<ItemViewModel>> Matrix { get; } = new List<List<Item>>()
    {
        new (){53, 2500, 3000, 3500, 4000, 4500, 5000},
        new (){2500, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
        new (){3000, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0},
        new (){3500, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0},
        new (){4000, 0, 0, 0},
        new (){4500, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0},
        new (){5000, 9, 7, 5, 4, 1, 1},
        new (){1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
        new (){2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
        new (){0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}
    };
}
```

[image]

Nice thing about this is that there's no need for code behind or generating bindings programmatically.

Comment: Thank you for answering with that approach. I already tested it. Looks like it works. I don't really know all of the elements that you used in xaml, but the concept is quite clear and of course, I can easily use it. Is there any way to make it editable? Sorry for not mentioning it in my question. I've tried to just replace TextBlock with TextBox but it didn't work and needs additional Path, and, as I'm not really familiar with this kind of binding, I don't know how to do this properly.

Comment: Do you want your changes to be reflected in the Matrix object?

Comment: Yes, so it should be like TwoWay binding.

Comment: To do that, instead of List<List<Object>> you need to have some sort of view model that contains the value and implements inotifypropertychanged. Then the TextBox Text binds to the value in that view model. You'd have to do this if you were using a DataGrid as well, since you can't have a two way binding to a value type in a collection. The value has to be exposed via a bindable property.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It looks tricky to do such a simple task. Probably, developers should simplify such things, but maybe there is a reason for that kind of thing. I've found a library that can handle my requirements: [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/276808/how-to-populate-a-wpf-grid-based-on-a-2-dimensional-array). Unfortunately, it doesn't support object type, but there is a string type that can represent everything I want at the time as well.

Comment: It's extremely easy to do. See my answer. If you want the type of each cell to be an object, it will support that too.