# how to add image thumbnail and normal texts columns to datagrid in WPF, C#?

Tags: c#, wpf, image, datagrid

I want to retrieve data(they are all image parameters) from csv file and display them in the datagrid. Alongside, each entry I want to display thumbnail of an image. How do I go about having both image and other entries in the datagrid ?
So, here I have

Entity

```
public class ImageProperties
{
     public string ImageThumbNailPath{ get; set;}
     public string ImageFileName{ get; set;}
     public double Sharpness{ get; set;}
     public int ImageWidth{ get; set;}
     public int ImageHt{ get; set;}
     ...
}
```

Xaml

```
<DataGrid x:Name="dataGridView" ItemsSource="{Binding ImagePropertiesList}" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
                    <DataGrid.Columns>
                        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Image">
                            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <Image Height="25" Width="50" Source="{Binding ImageThumbNailPath}" />
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                    </DataGrid.Columns>
                    </DataGrid>
```

From ViewModel:

```
var ImagePropertiesList = new ObservableCollection<ImageProperties>();
ImagePropertiesList.Add(new ImageProperties() { 
ImageThumbNailPath=@"C:\Users\imgIcon.tif", ImageFileName="imgIcon.tif", 
Sharpness = 4.5, ImageWidth=50, ImageHt = 50 });
```

With above, I'm neither able to see the image nor the text data...I see I'm not enabling a way to display the texts but not sure how I should do that when combining with image.

My ImageProperties class might get modified to include more properties hence i don't want to include something like below for each property.

```
<DataGridTextColumn Header="ImageWidth" Binding="{Binding ImageWidth}"/>
```

Is there a way I could still show the image in the first column and all other properties in subsequent columns ? Please, guide me.

Comment: Seems fine to me. Probably you have some binding errors.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [DataGrid shows path of image instead of image itself](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40358111/datagrid-shows-path-of-image-instead-of-image-itself)

Comment: I checked the binding, it looks good to me. I enabled binding for text under DataGridTextColumn  and now texts are displaying but i don't see the image yet. Any idea what i'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

*ImagePropertiesList* must be a public property in your ViewModel.

```
public ObservableCollection<ImageProperties> ImagePropertiesList
{
    get;
    set;
}
```

With this change you must then just remove *var* from your current instantiation of *ImagePropertiesList*

```
ImagePropertiesList = new ObservableCollection<ImageProperties>();
```

If this does not work make sure that the DataContext is set to your ViewModel.